# Why ConcurrentHashMap put() return null but the item is put successfully?

Tags: java

I defined a map like this:

```
private Map<Integer, MyTask> taskMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, MyTask>();
```

The call (taskMap is empty then) to put a task will return null and the logger call will throw null pointer exception due to the **addedTask.getTaskNameId()** call below.

```
MyTask addedTask = taskMap.put(task.getId(), task);
logger.logTask("added task", "TaskMgmtMgr::registerTask()", "added task=" + addedTask.getTaskNameId());
```

But I can verify that task was put in successfully with these statements immediately after above logger call:

```
private String getAvailableTaskListStr()
    {
        Collection<MyTask> tasks = taskMap.values();
        if (tasks.isEmpty())
        {
            return "No running task";
        }
        String nameList = "";
        int index = 0;
        for (MyTask task : tasks)
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                nameList += task;
            }
            else
            {
                nameList += ", task";
            }
            index++;
        }
        return "TotalTasks in TaskMap is " + index + ": " + nameList;
    }
```

I am confused. Anybody can explain this to me? I am using JDK 1.8.0_20.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map returns previous associate value. if there is no value associate previously than it will return `null`. that is why you are getting `null`.

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key

**just example:**

```
Map<Integer, String> taskMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
        String hello=taskMap.put(34, "Test1");
        System.out.println("hello "+hello);//It returns null
        hello=taskMap.put(34, "Test2");
        System.out.println("hello "+hello);//it returns Test1
```

**Output:**

```
hello null
hello Test1
```

Comment: so, how can I check if the put() is successful or not? always success?